# php upload class uploading error

Tags: php

I want image upload. I used this code but, didn't work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EffzM.png). Can you give information?

I looked, `if ($upload->uploaded)` then after it didn't work.

```
## Kategori ##
function kategori() {
    $islem = $_GET['islem']; 

    $post_kadi              = $_POST['kadi'];
    $post_ksef              = sef_link($post_kadi);
    $post_ksira             = trim($_POST['ksira']);
    $post_altkat            = $_POST['altkat'];
    $post_durum             = $_POST['durum'];
    $post_keywords          = $_POST['keywords'];

    $upload = new upload($_FILES['image_field']);
    $upload->file_auto_rename = true;
    $upload->image_resize = false;
    $upload->process('../../resimler');

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    // Gelen Sonuca Göre İşlem Yaptırıyoruz
    if($islem== kaydet) {   
        # Sınıfımızı Başlatıyoruz.

        # Dosya Yüklenmiş mi ?
        if ($upload->uploaded)
        {

            if ($upload->processed)
            {
                $yaz = mysql_query("INSERT INTO kategori (name, sef_name, ust_id, durum, resim, keywords) values ('$post_kadi', '$post_ksef', '$post_altkat', '$post_durum', '$upload->file_dst_name', '$post_keywords') ");
                $upload->clean();
                if($yaz) {
                    Header("Location:../index.php?sayfa=kategori&durum=1");
                }
                else {
                    Header("Location:../index.php?sayfa=kategori&durum=2");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this upload class? Also stop using `mysql_` it's deprecated.

Comment: Also `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of the page may yield the answer.